# Changing implementation of SAP Note 303453 - User exits for shipping data determination in STO

Tags: abap, sap-erp, sap-basis

I posted the [same question](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3870762) is [scn.sap](http://scn.sap.com) but I haven't receive any answer so I'll try here hoping that I'll have excellent answers as usual:

I need to set the field 'Order Combination Indicator' in the 'Shipping' tab in transaction 'ME21N' and 'ME59N' however I haven't found an enhancement or BADi to make this possible. The goal is to set this indicator so transaction 'VL10B' can combine the deliveries.

[image]

Making an investigation I found the SAP Note '303453 - User exits for shipping data determination in STO' which makes possible to change shipping values in the purchase order but this modification does not include the field 'Order Combination Indicator' (EKPV-KZAZU).

I've checked the code inside the SAP Note and I realize that the form 'PTV_FUELLEN' in the include 'MM06EFPV_PTV_FUELLEN' could be changed so I would add the line:

ptv-kzazu = ekpv-kzazu.

Between 'ptv-vsbed = ekpv-vsbed.' and 'if ptv-updkz is initial'.

[image]

The same would be done in the includes 'MM06EFPV_PTV_FUELLEN_RETOURE_F' and 'MM06EFPV_PTV_FUELLEN_RETOURE_L' which are part of the modification.

This change could make the trick however I'm not sure if it's something that I'm authorized to do because it's a modification. On the other what does the yellow indicator with the message 'Corrections incompletely copied: see change display' means.

[image]

The following code is the provided by the SAP Note:

```
  *$*$----------------------------------------------------------------$*$*
  *$ Correction Inst. 0120061532 0001770752 $*
  *$--------------------------------------------------------------------$*
  *$ Valid for : $*
  *$ Software Component SAP_APPL SAP Application $*
  *$ Release 470 All Support Package Levels $*
  *$ Release 500 Fm SAPKH50001 $*
  *$ Release 600 Fm SAPKH60001 $*
  *$ Release 602 All Support Package Levels $*
  *$ Release 603 All Support Package Levels $*
  *$ Release 604 Fm SAPKH60401 $*
  *$--------------------------------------------------------------------$*
  *$ Changes/Objects Not Contained in Standard SAP System $*
  *$*$----------------------------------------------------------------$*$*
  *&--------------------------------------------------------------------*
  *& Object REPS MM06EFPV_PTV_FUELLEN_RETOURE_F
  *& Object Header PROG MM06EFPV_PTV_FUELLEN_RETOURE_F
  *&--------------------------------------------------------------------*
  *& FORM PTV_FUELLEN_RETOURE_FIL
  *&--------------------------------------------------------------------*
  ...
  ENDCASE.
  ENDIF.
  ENDIF.

  *>>>> START OF DELETION <<<<<
  CHECK im_activity NE 'C'. "nicht beim Check
  *>>>> END OF DELETION <<<<<<<
  *>>>> START OF INSERTION <<<<
  READ TABLE ptv WITH KEY potkey BINARY SEARCH.
  IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
  ptv-lprio = ekpv-lprio.
  ptv-vstel = ekpv-vstel.
  ptv-route = ekpv-route.
  ptv-vsbed = ekpv-vsbed.
  IF ptv-updkz is initial.
  ptv-updkz = 'U'.
  ENDIF.
  MODIFY ptv INDEX sy-tabix.
  ENDIF.

  CHECK im_activity NE 'C'. "nicht beim Check

  *>>>> END OF INSERTION <<<<<<
  ...
  *&--------------------------------------------------------------------*
  *&--------------------------------------------------------------------*
  *& Object REPS MM06EFPV_PTV_FUELLEN
  *& Object Header PROG MM06EFPV_PTV_FUELLEN
  *&--------------------------------------------------------------------*
  *& FORM PTV_FUELLEN
  *&--------------------------------------------------------------------*
  ...
  else.
  check sy-subrc eq 0.
  ENDIF.
  *>>>> START OF DELETION <<<<<
  CHECK im_activity NE 'C'.
  *>>>> END OF DELETION <<<<<<<
  *>>>> START OF INSERTION <<<<
  READ TABLE ptv WITH KEY potkey BINARY SEARCH.
  if sy-subrc eq 0.
  ptv-lprio = ekpv-lprio.
  ptv-vstel = ekpv-vstel.
  ptv-route = ekpv-route.
  ptv-vsbed = ekpv-vsbed.
  if ptv-updkz is initial.
  ptv-updkz = 'U'.
  endif.
  modify ptv index sy-tabix.
  endif.

  CHECK im_activity NE 'C'.
  *>>>> END OF INSERTION <<<<<<
  ...
  *&--------------------------------------------------------------------*
```

How should I proceed in this case?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that application, but form ptv_fuellen does have 2 enhancement-points. You could add your code there and stay supported.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, I would like to add a line that is not included in the modification of the SAP Note. My goal is to set the value of the field PTV-KZAZU. The fact is I don't know if I'm authorized to do so.

Comment: you don't have to change the SAP note contents. You create your own new implementation for the enhancement point. Both implementations will be executed. Check here for details on how to create new implementations: http://scn.sap.com/people/thomas.weiss/blog/2006/05/03/source-code-enhancements--part-5-of-the-series-on-the-new-enhancement-framework . The implementation part starts at heading "Implementing an Enhancement Point" but the whole article is a good read to understand the "new" source code enhancement option.